# How can I use a gitian environment for building a local project?

Tags: gcc, bitcoin, lxc

I'm working on a project (a fork of bitcoin) that has initially been commited to github that uses the gitian build system. At this point I'd like to set up a local environment that allows me to change code and test changes without commiting them to a git repository.

Is there a way to configure gitian to work with local files that don't have a corresponding git repository, taking advantage of the deterministic build environment without the integrity checks?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else happens to be dealing with the same tools, the answer is very simple. You can specify a local git repository with filesystem path instead of a remote git URL in your .yml gitian descriptor file.

```
remotes:
- "url": "/home/user/project"
  "dir": "project"
```

Then branch off your project and commit your changes with git.

When running gbuild, specify the branch/commit with --commit project=branchname.

Comment: +1 that's the most elegant solution, I actually just made a local bare repository and used that instead of the remote / github url - everything else is pretty much the same, I can adjust things locally while testing/tweaking - a only push to remote once all is tested out.